# How to make line graph in plot_ly that has multiple Y axis?

Tags: r, r-plotly

Following is the output I wanted in plotly ( I got this in ggplot2).

[image]

When I tried in ploty I received the following out put.

[image]

following is the script I used.

```
    data1 <-  data  %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date))

chart <-  plot_ly(data = data1,
                 x = ~ Date)

chart <- chart %>%  add_trace(y= ~Name1,name = "Name1", type = "scatter", mode = 'markers+lines')
chart <- chart %>%  add_trace(y= ~Name2, name = "Name2", mode = 'markers+lines', type = "scatter")
chart <- chart %>%  add_trace(y= ~weight, name = "weight", mode = 'markers+lines', type = "scatter")

chart
```

please help me solve this

Answer (score 0):

`plotly` starts drawing the graphs row by row. So date and value of the first row will be connect with a line to the second row and so on. When your dataset is not arranged by the x-variable (`date`), `plotly` will still connect row by row and won't care if the dates are ordered or not.

So try to arrange the dataset by `Date`. - Please have a look at your code above, your dataset is not reproducable. Therefore it's hard to tell, if this is the solution to your problem.

**Code Example unordered**

```
data1 <- data.frame(Date = ymd(20210101:20210105),
                 Name1 = sample(50:200,5),
                 Name2 = sample(50:200, 5),
                 weight = sample(50:200, 5)) %>%
  mutate(Date = sample(Date))

head(data1)
Date Name1 Name2 weight
1 2021-01-05    88   139    153
2 2021-01-02   136   162    109
3 2021-01-01    66   104    179
4 2021-01-03   145   147     70
5 2021-01-04   189   181    136

chart <-  plot_ly(data = data1,
                  x = ~ Date)
chart <- chart %>%  add_trace(y= ~Name1,name = "Name1", type = "scatter", mode = 'markers+lines')
chart <- chart %>%  add_trace(y= ~Name2, name = "Name2", mode = 'markers+lines', type = "scatter")
chart <- chart %>%  add_trace(y= ~weight, name = "weight", mode = 'markers+lines', type = "scatter")

chart
```

**Example Plot  unordered**
[image]

**Example Data ordered**

```
data_arrange <- data1 %>% 
  arrange(Date)

head(data_arrange)
Date Name1 Name2 weight
1 2021-01-01    66   104    179
2 2021-01-02   136   162    109
3 2021-01-03   145   147     70
4 2021-01-04   189   181    136
5 2021-01-05    88   139    153

chart <-  plot_ly(data = data_arrange,
                  x = ~ Date)
chart <- chart %>%  add_trace(y= ~Name1,name = "Name1", type = "scatter", mode = 'markers+lines')
chart <- chart %>%  add_trace(y= ~Name2, name = "Name2", mode = 'markers+lines', type = "scatter")
chart <- chart %>%  add_trace(y= ~weight, name = "weight", mode = 'markers+lines', type = "scatter")
chart
```

**Example Plot ordered**
[image]